# Why won't cubes appear, using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so I'm pretty deep in a project modifying a CSS and HTML version of KuKu Kube, and I'm attempting to get all of the squares to be the same size, and there to be the same number of cubes in each level. Now, something that was provided before was a generator function for the cubes, as follows:

```
 var inputs = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      for (var n = 0; n < (99); n++) {
        inputs += '<input type="checkbox" onchange="timerfunc()" class="cube cube_' + n + ' level_' + i + '" />';
      }
    }
    inputs += '<div class="finish">Game Complete!</div>';
    document.getElementById('game').innerHTML = inputs;
```

So, that code seems to have worked, but I have messed with something, and now only the first level appears. The CSS is ~1000 lines, so I won't post it here, but the JSFiddle I'm working at is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/88naxrjo/24/).

Novice programmer (me) messed something up, and I have no idea what it was, nor why it's not working. I'd appreciate any help you guys could give.

Comment: Why is your script in the `HTML` section of the fiddle?

Comment: Dunno, it was like it before, would porting it into the JS section change anything?

Comment: What is the code supposed to be doing? Is there an example anywhere?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/88naxrjo/26/ I've moved the code over to the JS section, what is it not doing that you're expecting it to do?

Comment: Notice that when you click the red cube, the second level does not show up, which it should.